Bash/Dialog: Script exits when I Right click and paste anything into the input box of the dialog screen
Here's a dialog based bash script prompting user for input.
User is able to type into the input fields fine but right clicking and pasting into the input field causes the script to exit and pastes the input on the terminal instead surrounded by tilde (e.g ~input~).
But if I just simply copy paste into the terminal, it pastes fine(without the tilde).
#!/bin/bash

FORM_DATA=$(dialog --title "Mixed Form" --backtitle "Mixed Form" \
                --mixedform "This is simple mixedform :" 40 100 0 \
                "URL 1      :" 1 10 ""  1 30 200 0 0 \
                "URL 2      :" 2 10 ""  2 30  200 0 0 \
                "URL 3      :" 3 10 ""  3 30  200 0 0 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
URL_1=$(echo "$FORM_DATA" | sed -n '1p')
URL_2=$(echo "$FORM_DATA" | sed -n '2p')
URL_3=$(echo "$FORM_DATA" | sed -n '3p')
echo $URL_1
echo $URL_2
echo $URL_3

Trying to copy paste, say, https://www.abc.lmn/pqr.bin into any of the fields causes the skip to exit with ~https://www.abc.lmn/pqr.bin~ displayed on the terminal.
Upon simple right click and paste into the Terminal itself pastes the url as https://www.abc.lmn/pqr.bin fine.
Any help will be appreciated.

Which terminal emulator does this happen on?
